# Displaying a separator view in CollectionView

Tags: marionette

I've got a Collection that is sorted by model's datetime property. I need to display a 'separator view' whenever the day changes. I was thinking about using a CollectionView to display the data. Am I on the right track?

The end result would look something like this:

```
1st of September (separator view)
-----------------------------
Model1
Model2

2nd of September (separator view)
-----------------------------
Model3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to extend the CollectionView's appendHtml method.

```
appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView, index) ->
  if @_isDayChanged index
    itemView.separator = true
    itemView.render()
  super
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a list of `CompositeView`s to divide collection items in groups by month. You can easily adapt it to group by days.

```
let ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  ...
});

let ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  childView: ItemView,
  template: template,
  childViewContainer: '.items',

  filter(child) {
    return child.get('month') === this.model.get('month');
  }
});

let MonthGroupedListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  childView: ListView,

  childViewOptions(item, index) {
    return {
      model: item,
      collection: this.getOption('collection')
    };
  },

  initialize() {
    // Passed collection remains in this.options.collection
    // this.collection will contain distinct months
    this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    this.reset();

    this.listenTo(this.options.collection, 'sync update', this.reset);
  },

  reset() {
    // Find distnct months and put them into the collection
    let months = _.uniq(this.options.collection.map((model) => model.get('month')));

    this.collection.reset(_.map(months, (month) => ({month})));
  }

});
```

From the data below the result should be three groups of `ListView`:

```
let data = [
  { id: 1, month: '2015-01', title: "January item 1" },
  { id: 2, month: '2015-01', title: "January item 2" },
  { id: 3, month: '2015-02', title: "February item 1" },
  { id: 4, month: '2015-05', title: "May item 1" },
  { id: 5, month: '2015-05', title: "May item 2" },
  { id: 6, month: '2015-05', title: "May item 3" }
];

let view = new MonthGroupedListView({
  collection: new Backbone.Collection(data)
});
```

The template for `ListView` looks like this:

```
<div class="month-header">
    {{month}}
</div>
<ul class="items">
    {{-- Here ItemView elements will be rendered --}}
</ul>
```